# Unmarshal JSON dynamically into structs containing only top level fields based on a type field

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

Say I have the following event structs that I cannot modify (not even the tags):

```golang
type openAudioStream struct {
    Type     string `json:"type"`
    ID       string `json:"id"`
    Address  string `json:"address"`
    Channels int    `json:"channels"`
}

type openVideoStream struct {
    Type        string `json:"type"`
    ID          string `json:"id"`
    Address     string `json:"address"`
    AspectRatio string `json:"aspectRatio"`
}
```

And I have an API endpoint which emits JSON strings (that I also cannot modify) containing events that map to either one of those two structs and I cannot tell in advance which one it is, so I need to, somehow, extract the type field to figure out which struct to instantiate and then unmarshal the rest of the JSON into the instantiated event object.

The first approach that came to my mind was to call `json.Unmarshal` twice like so:

```golang
func jsonUnmarshal(payload []byte) (Event, error) {
    eventType := struct {
        Type string
    }{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &eventType)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }

    var event Event
    switch eventType.Type {
    case "audio":
        event = &openAudioStream{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(payload, event)
    case "video":
        event = &openVideoStream{}
        err = json.Unmarshal(payload, event)
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("unrecognised event type: %s", eventType.Type)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }

    return event, nil
}
```

While this works well, it's inefficient to traverse the JSON string twice, so I thought that, maybe, I can create a union type and use that to unmarshal the JSON like so:

```golang
func notWorking(payload []byte) (Event, error) {
    eventUnion := struct {
        Type string `json:"type"`
        openAudioStream
        openVideoStream
    }{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &eventUnion)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }

    var event Event
    switch eventUnion.Type {
    case "audio":
        event = &extractor.openAudioStream
    case "video":
        event = &extractor.openVideoStream
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unrecognised event type: %s", eventUnion.Type)
    }

    return event, nil
}
```

Besides being an ugly hack, this approach doesn't work if the embedded structs contain conflicting fields. The json unmarshaler simply [ignores them](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11006) without producing any error.

Finally, I recalled that [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) might help and, indeed, I am able to use it like so:

```golang
func mapstructureDecode(payload []byte) (Event, error) {
    var unmarshaledPayload map[string]interface{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &unmarshaledPayload)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }

    var ok bool
    var val interface{}
    var eventType string
    if val, ok = unmarshaledPayload["type"]; ok {
        eventType, ok = val.(string)
    }
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to determine event type: %v", err)
    }

    var event Event
    switch eventType {
    case "audio":
        event = &openAudioStream{}
        err = mapstructure.Decode(unmarshaledPayload, &event)
    case "video":
        event = &openVideoStream{}
        err = mapstructure.Decode(unmarshaledPayload, event)
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("unrecognised event type: %s", eventType)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }

    return event, nil
}
```

However, using this library seems a bit overkill for this task and it requires adding `mapstructure` tags to the struct fields if the input JSON doesn't follow the standard naming conventions, which is an issue if I have, for example `aspect_ratio` instead of `aspectRatio`.

The full code for the above experiments can be found here: https://play.golang.org/p/qTGoV6i8m5P

I'm curious if there is any other way to tackle this problem using existing libraries. I was thinking that maybe some creative use of `json.RawMessage` and a custom `UnmarshalJSON` method might help, but this doesn't seem to be of use if I have only top level fields in the event structs.

Comment: I'd use the first approach but change eventType to contain the union of all fields (without embedding though) and just copy the fields to either an openAudioStream or openVideoStream, depending on the type field. Unless the types are much larger in reality, or there are many more types; then unmarshaling twice is the way to go.

Comment: @Peter Yeah, unmarshaling twice is probably the least painful approach. Not sure I understand why it would be useful for `eventType` to contain the union of all fields, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can unmarshal once in combined struct and then create new struct depends on type.

```
func jsonUnmarshal(payload []byte) (Event, error) {
    data := struct {
        Type        string
        ID          string
        Address     string
        Channels    int
        AspectRatio string
    }{}
    // Unmarshal in combined stuct
    err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }
    var event Event
    switch data.Type {
    case "audio":
        // Creating new stuct 
        event = &openAudioStream{Type: data.Type, ID: data.ID, Address: data.Address, Channels: data.Channels}
    case "video":
        event = &openVideoStream{Type: data.Type, ID: data.ID, Address: data.Address, AspectRatio: data.AspectRatio}
    default:
        err = fmt.Errorf("unrecognised event type: %s", data.Type)
    }
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON: %v", err)
    }
    return event, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have considered it, but it's brittle, because each time a field gets added into one of the event structs, I have to add it to this combined struct. Also, creating that intermediary struct and copying its fields around is not very efficient. It's better than parsing the JSON string twice, I suppose, but still.

Comment: Actually I don't think it can be more better first, I just want to give you a way without 2 times unmarshal and intermediary struct is need for one field or many cost same.

Comment: And twice unmarshal is very costly, just do a quick test with your code with mine for 1000 times same event then you can see which one faster.

Comment: Consider this way you have to unmarshal once and if I am not wrong every time 4 field data only will come. (mandatory) , so extra portion of my solution is copying its fields, think as you work conditional you have to again must do it. And you are sending interface{} from function so you can send the combined struct also